# Vuejs Parent-Child Communication Issues w/Single Value

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, parent-child, vue-component, reactive-programming

So, in Vuejs, I've created a dropdown component that is called like so:

```
                        <Dropdown
                        :style="{width: '100%'}"
                        v-on:selectReturn='selectReturn'
                        :dropDataArray="expenseType"/>

                        <Dropdown
                        :style="{width: '100%'}"
                        v-on:selectReturn='selectReturn'
                        :dropDataArray="loanType"/>
```

where in data I have

```
    expenseType: [
        'expenseType',
        'one time',
        'recurring',
        'loan'
    ], 
    loanType: [
        'loanType',
        'new loan',
        'recurring payment',
        'one time payment'
    ]
```

In the child I need to read the first line of the array, for various reasons.

So I have...

`props: ['dropDataArray']`

and...

`this.dataArrayName = this.dropDataArray[0];`

HOWEVER:

console logging the `this.dataArrayName` value is showing that it changes the first child components 0th item to 'loanType' (I call this on an @click). This is very strange as I am not passing the first Dropdown child the loanType array! I think I'm falling afoul of the reactivity caveats for vuejs, but I don't see how, or the best way to change this. If anyone has any ideas please let me know. Thanks!

Here is a codesandbox.io link https://codesandbox.io/s/x38j14900q.

You'll find the problem if you click the top select box and look in the console. You'lll see this:

`value of this.dataArrayName:  loanType`

when really it should be ExpenseType!

Further testing is showing that the problem is worse than I expected.

```
                        <Dropdown
                        :style="{width: '100%'}"
                        :stringProp="'expenseString'"
                        :dropDataArray="expenseType"/>

                        <Dropdown
                        :style="{width: '100%'}"
                        :stringProp="'loanString'"
                        :dropDataArray="expenseType"/>
```

with `props: ['dropDataArray', 'stringProp']`

is again only returning `loanString`

Comment: Can you include the code for your `Dropdown` component, or a re-producible example of the problem on http://jsfiddle.net/ or https://codesandbox.io/? Arrays are passed by reference, and it seems you may be mutating `dropDataArray` from within your `Dropdown` component.

Comment: If you switch the Dropdown order, is the first item 'expenseType'?

Comment: are you closing the component i dont see `</dropdown`

Comment: Do you have them wrapped in a `<keep-alive>...</keep-alive>`?

Comment: I close dropdown with a `/>`. I've included a codesandbox that illustrates the problem in my question above. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a scoping issue in `window.onclick`. The actual value of `dataArrayName` doesn't change. Your window event probably takes it's value from last rendered `Dropdown` component.

I've changed your example app a bit:
https://codesandbox.io/s/rrpq67q9ro

What I added is an interval which displays `dataArrayName` every 3 seconds for logging. As you can see, it's displaying both `expenseType` and `loanType`. I also added a `test(e)` method and I moved the contents of your `window.onclick` to this method. `test` is run when you click the dropdown. If you look at console now, it displays correct `dataArrayName` depending on which instance of Dropdown you clicked.

Comment: Gah...I saw this like 2 seconds ago. I award you all the points and may you walk in the glory of the divine source code. Many thanks kind stranger :D